# $state.reload() moves to parent's $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm implementing some kind of dynamic workflow and when I reach a certain point I must reload my state to render the HTML and reinstantiate the controller in order to continue.

What I've found is that the second time that I call `$state.reload()` is not working. Is this the desired behavior? What can I do to force this reload?

```
if(advanceComplexAction()) {
  console.log(self.$state); //This is always been printed in console
  self.$state.reload();
}
else {
  closeActionWizard();
}
```

I'm checking my console and the console.log is always printed but my statement `self.$state.reload()` only runs correctly the first time that I call it.

EDIT:

I noticed that my url change when I do the first reload and is changing to the parent URL. That must be the problem because the third time it only reload the parentState. I don't know how to solve this

First time that is working correctly my url is:

```
http://localhost:1234/app/parentstate/childstate
```

After using reload and everything worked it moves to the parent state.

```
http://localhost:1234/app/parentstate
```

So when I do reload again it only reloads the parent view. I'm defining my routes as follow.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, modalStateProvider){
  $stateProvider

.state('app.parentstate',
  modalStateProvider.create({
    animation: true,
    name: 'app.parentsate',
    url: 'apps/parentstate',
    controllerAs: 'parentCtrl',
    controller: 'ParentCtrl',
    windowClass: 'semi-modal semi-modal--XXL',
    templateUrl: function() {
      return 'app/ui/apps/parent/parent.html';
    },
    resolve: {
      //Some resolve function
      }]
    }
  })
)
.state('app.parentstate.childstate',
  modalStateProvider.create({
    animation: true,
    name: 'app.parentstate.childstate',
    url: '/childstate',
    controllerAs: 'childWizardCtrl',
    controller: 'ChildWizardCtrl',
    windowClass: 'semi-modal semi-modal--XL',
    templateUrl: function(){
      return 'app/ui/apps/child/child.html';
    }
  })
)
```

Thank you

Comment: As always - creating super simple ```plnkr``` example will make your question more likely to get answered...

Comment: I always used $state.reload(). I am interested to know about **self** (self.$state)

Comment: @DineshSundaraneedi I added more code and edited what I discovered

Comment: so you need to reload only  the child state ?

Comment: yes, that's what I want. I don'w know why after reload is moving to another state

Comment: can i ask you what happen if you reload with F5 (o cmd+r)?

Comment: @hayatoShingu My url remains the same but my controller is not working properly because I'm missing some necessary data that comes from my parent state.

Comment: Try without the resolve to see what happen

Comment: @hayatoShingu After the reload I debugged and the $state dependency that is injected have been changed for another who is the father $state and not the actual one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it! The problem was with my implementation of modalState. I have an OnEnter function that moves to my parent state automatically if my state is the same or if I close it.

```
        modalInstance.result
      .then(function(result) {
        $log.debug('Modal result', result);
      }, function(rejection) {
        $log.debug('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date() + ' because ' + rejection);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        modalInstance = null;
        if ($state.$current.name === options.name) {
          $state.go('^', $stateParams, { reload: options.reload }); //Here we are moving to parent state
        }
      });
```

Changing this fixed my problem. Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you sould try something like

```
$state.transitionTo('current_state', null, {'reload':true});
```

Comment: No, when I do that my $state is moving to the parent one.

Comment: did you replace 'current_state'  by $state.current or whatever you need ?

Comment: yes. I don't know whats happening with my app that when I do the reload. The $state dependency that is injected change to the one from the parent and in that moment is when it breaks

Comment: Do you have any $stateChangeSuccess or $stateChangeStart  event in your coude?

Answer (score 0):

I get it !

```
$state.reload();
```

is an alias for

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true });
```

"reload:true" refresh the parent state ! so you need to avoid using "$state.reload"

Try instead

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

Comment: that's not working because is reloading my whole app and I'm losing some valuable information. I need to reload only the child state. I noticed that I'm getting the problem in my whole application. In every state that I try to reload my state after reloading the injected $state is changed to the parent one.